# CSS - Make outside text not move when inside text changes

Tags: html, css

How do I make it so that when I change the text between 2 span elements that they do not move left or right?

This is what the HTML looks like (the `table-layout` is `fixed`):

```
<td>
    <span class='sub'>-</span>
    <span class='amount'>0</span>
    <span class='add'>+</span>
</td>
```

I would like the `amount` to change without the `-` and `+` spans to moved (the amount will remain a small number so I'm not worried about overlapping), because when I go from `0` to `1` the `-` and `+` spans move closer together. It's not a huge inconvenience, so I don't want a convoluted CSS or JavaScript hack, I'm just wondering.

Comment: maybe add display:block to your spans? (if I understand the question correctly)

Comment: `display` the `.amount` as `inline-block` and give it an explicit `width`?

Comment: @BillK Changing their display's to `block` makes them stack on top of each other, which I don't want, and changing it to `inline-block` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @StrongJoshua Have you tried giving it an explicit `width`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span is inline element, so that unlike block-level element (e.g. div) it ignores user-defined width and the width is calculated by browser during the stage known as layout or reflow. Knowing this all you need to do is forcing the element to behave as a block by setting its **display** css property and giving it some fixed **width**:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.block-span {   
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block; 
 } 
</style>

...
<span class="amount block-span">0</span>
...
```